# Fetch multiple users from Sharepoint UserProfile Servce

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I need to fetch all users ID from their Manager in Sharepoint userprofile..
Means Multiple users are under of a single Manager.
Using C# how to fetch?
Anyone knows..Help me.

Answer (score -1):

Should be able to do something like.

```
SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Site);
UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
UserProfile u = upm.GetUserProfile(false);
var users = u.GetDirectReports();
```

Be sure to include a reference to Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles